# Trim text for received email

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

I wanted to write in react and Recipients panel which tries to display all the Recipients from a sender :

If all the recipient email addresses fit in the available space, I want to display them separate by a coma.
When there is not enough space to display all recipients, we trim the text and we try to show as much as we can of Recipients.
[I join an image of what I wanted to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVUqF.png)
I am really bad at css but here what I managed to do so :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      if (containerRef.current) {
        const containerWidth = containerRef.current.offsetWidth;
        const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
        setShowAll(containerWidth >= screenWidth);
      }
    };

    handleResize();

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, [recipients]);

  const displayRecipients = showAll ? recipients : recipients.slice(0, calculateVisibleRecipients(recipients));

  return (
    <div
      ref={containerRef}
      className={`recipients-display ${showAll ? 'show-all' : ''}`}
      style={{ whiteSpace: 'nowrap', overflow: 'hidden', textOverflow: 'ellipsis', maxWidth: '100vw' }}
    >
      {displayRecipients.join(', ')}
      {!showAll && recipients.length > displayRecipients.length && (
        <span className="badge">+{recipients.length - displayRecipients.length}</span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

and the Css :

```
.content {
  display: flex; /* Make the content a flex container */
  justify-content: space-between; /* Space between text and badge */
  align-items: center; /* Align vertically in the center */
}

.badge {
  background-color: #666666; /* Customize the badge background color */
  color:  #f0f0f0; /* Customize the badge text color */
  padding: 2px 5px;
  margin-left: 10px; /* Margin from the end of the line */
  border-radius: "3px";
}

.overflow-indicator {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #777; /* Customize the overflow indicator color */
}
```

Thank so much again for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried [`text-overflow: ellipsis;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)?

Comment: Yes but here the thing : if the email is too long I prefer to display …